# Argument 1 passed to pluginSplit() must be of the type string, array given

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-4.x

I'm currently attempting a migration from `3.10.2` to `4.0`. I've gone through the guide and I'm now   trying to fix issues as they come up.

I'm finding this one rather cryptic.

`Argument 1 passed to pluginSplit() must be of the type string, array given, called in C:\path\to\app\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Core\ObjectRegistry.php on line 300`

I suspect it's related to loading plugins. I'm not finding any references to my own files in the stack trace:

```
Error in: ROOT\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Core\functions.php, line 89

pluginSplit
CORE\src\Core\ObjectRegistry.php:300
Cake\Core\ObjectRegistry->normalizeArray
CORE\src\View\View.php:1091
Cake\View\View->loadHelpers
CORE\src\View\View.php:350
Cake\View\View->__construct
CORE\src\View\ViewBuilder.php:556
Cake\View\ViewBuilder->build
CORE\src\View\ViewVarsTrait.php:74
Cake\Controller\Controller->createView
CORE\src\Controller\Controller.php:687
Cake\Controller\Controller->render
CORE\src\Controller\Controller.php:530
Cake\Controller\Controller->invokeAction
CORE\src\Controller\ControllerFactory.php:79
Cake\Controller\ControllerFactory->invoke
CORE\src\Http\BaseApplication.php:229
Cake\Http\BaseApplication->handle
CORE\src\Http\Runner.php:77
Cake\Http\Runner->handle
CORE\src\Http\Runner.php:77
Cake\Http\Runner->handle
CORE\src\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware.php:128
Cake\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware->process
CORE\src\Http\Runner.php:73
Cake\Http\Runner->handle
CORE\src\Http\Runner.php:58
Cake\Http\Runner->run
CORE\src\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php:166
Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->process
CORE\src\Http\Runner.php:73
Cake\Http\Runner->handle
CORE\src\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware.php:68
Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware->process
CORE\src\Http\Runner.php:73
Cake\Http\Runner->handle
CORE\src\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php:119
Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->process
CORE\src\Http\Runner.php:73
Cake\Http\Runner->handle
CORE\src\Http\Runner.php:58
Cake\Http\Runner->run
CORE\src\Http\Server.php:90
Cake\Http\Server->run
ROOT\webroot\index.php:40
```

**Edit #1**

It's failing on the 3rd line:

```
$this->loadComponent("WetKit.WetKit");
$this->viewBuilder()->setHelpers(['WetKit.Wet']);
$this->viewBuilder()->setHelpers(['Form', ['templates' => 'WetKit.wet_form']]);
$this->viewBuilder()->setTheme('WetKit');
```

Comment: If you look at the top of the stack it's related to loading helpers. Check where you configure helpers, there's probably something being defined incorrectly.

Comment: Making progress. See edit #1. I found the line that was causing the issue. I was moving away from the `$helpers` configuration using the suggested `setHelpers` and it seems I'm not passing the appropriate array structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you define the options for the helper is wrong, it must be defined as the value for an array key, not as a separate array entry, otherwise that array is being passed into the logic that parses the helper name, resulting in the error that you're seeing.

Long story short:

```php
$this->viewBuilder()->setHelpers([
    'Form' => [
        'templates' => 'WetKit.wet_form'
    ],
]);
```

I feel like there's some documentation missing for how to set/add helpers with configuration. You might want to open an issue for that over at [**GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/docs/issues).

Comment: What you suggested worked! Making head ways into this migration, finally! Thanks. Also, I had attempted to translate the existing $helper structure into this new way of doing things and obviously failed. I also applied this logic to other helpers, which were also formatted this way.